# String 3 decimal places

Tags: vb.net, string, format

### Example 1

```
Dim myStr As String = "38"
```

I want my result to be `38.000` ...

---

### Example 2

```
myStr = "6.4"
```

I want my result to be `6.400`

---

What is the best method to achieve this? I want to format a **string** variable with atleast *three decimal* places.

Comment: Are you really starting with a **String** value?

Comment: Probably not what you intended, but if it's simply a string than `Dim myStr As String = "38.000"` and `Dim myStr As String = "6.4000"` would work.  I think you're actually asking how to convert a string representation of a number to a decimal, yes?

Comment: the result of assigning a `String` literal to a variable?

Comment: Editted so it makes more sense

Comment: only makes sense if Fred.000 is an acceptable output...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [FormatNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfta99yt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
Dim myStr As String = "38"
MsgBox(FormatNumber(CDbl(myStr), 3))

Dim myStr2 As String = "6.4"
MsgBox(FormatNumber(CDbl(myStr2), 3))
```

Comment: Just be careful. The assumption that the value is a number in an acceptable format is iffy. 0.0001, would be a possible issue as well.

Comment: True, you really shouldn't be storing numbers as strings, you should convert them to strings when needed.

Answer (score 4):

So if you have

```
Dim thirtyEight = "38"
Dim sixPointFour = "6.4"
```

Then, the best way to parse those to a numeric type is, [`Double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse.aspx) or [`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx), you should keep your data typed until you want to display it to the user.

Then, if you want to [format a string with 3 decimal places](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), do somthing like `String.Format("{0:N3}", value)`.

So, if you want a quick hack for the problem,

```
Dim yourString = String.Format("{0:N3}", Double.Parse("38"))
```

would do.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on ["Standard Numeric Format Strings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

```
float value = 6.4f;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("N3", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 6.400
```

Comment: or, simpler `Console.WriteLine("{0:N3}", value)`

Comment: But my value is initially a string. Not a decimal. So when I try to format it using ToString() I get a System.IFormatProvider error

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo code

```
decpoint = Value.IndexOf(".");
If decpoint < 0 
  return String.Concat(value,".000")
else
  return value.PadRight(3 - (value.length - decpoint),"0")
```

If it's string keep it as a string. If it's a number pass it as one.